# Magento 2 Calling phtml file using controller

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to call a phtml file using controller below is my code and i dont know why it is not working

**Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $requestforquoteFactory;

    protected $requestforquote;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\RequestForQuoteFactory $requestforquoteFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\RequestForQuote $requestforquote
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->requestforquoteFactory = $requestforquoteFactory;
        $this->requestforquote = $requestforquote;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
   
    public function execute()
    {

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        try{

            $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $name = $request['name'];
            $company = $request['company'];
            $phonenumber = $request['phonenumber'];
            $email = $request['email'];
            // $email = $request['email'];
            $gstnumber = $request['gstnumber'];
    
            $requestforquote = $this->requestforquoteFactory->create();

             $requestforquote->setName($name);
             $requestforquote->setCompany($company);
             $requestforquote->setPhoneNumber($phonenumber);
             $requestforquote->setGSTNumber($gstnumber);
             $requestforquote->setEmail($email);
             $requestforquote->save();
            
            $message = __('Thank you! Your Quote Has Been Submitted');
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

            $this->resultPageFactory->create();
           // return $resultRedirect->setPath('requestforquote/index/index');
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
            $this->_view->renderLayout();
            $this->_view->loadLayout();

        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t submit your request, Please try again.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            //return $resultRedirect->setPath('requestforquote/index/index');
        }

    }

    public function test(){


        //$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rfq')
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::rfq_form.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
         $this->_view->renderLayout();
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
    }

}
?>
```

**am getting a blank page when i hit controller**

Answer (score 2):

Do not need to add

```
$this->_view->renderLayout();
$this->_view->loadLayout();
```

**Page resultPageFactory already include layout object to the page.**

```
public function execute()
{

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $blockHtml = $resultPage->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
        ->setBlockId('CMB_BLOCK_IDENTIFIER')
        ->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($blockHtml);
    return;
}
```

**Here the modified code:**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $requestforquoteFactory;

    protected $requestforquote;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\RequestForQuoteFactory $requestforquoteFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\RequestForQuote $requestforquote
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->requestforquoteFactory = $requestforquoteFactory;
        $this->requestforquote = $requestforquote;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
   
    public function execute()
    {

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        try{

            $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $name = $request['name'];
            $company = $request['company'];
            $phonenumber = $request['phonenumber'];
            $email = $request['email'];
            // $email = $request['email'];
            $gstnumber = $request['gstnumber'];
    
            $requestforquote = $this->requestforquoteFactory->create();

             $requestforquote->setName($name);
             $requestforquote->setCompany($company);
             $requestforquote->setPhoneNumber($phonenumber);
             $requestforquote->setGSTNumber($gstnumber);
             $requestforquote->setEmail($email);
             $requestforquote->save();
            
            $message = __('Thank you! Your Quote Has Been Submitted');
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $blockHtml = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rfq')
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::rfq_form.phtml')
                ->toHtml();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($blockHtml);
            return;   

        }catch (\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t submit your request, Please try again.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: i am still getting blank page when i hit controller am also sharing my phtml file as well as layout file

Comment: check updated question

Comment: `$this->getResponse()->setBody('test-work');`

Comment: changes from `$this->getResponse()->setBody($blockHtml);`  and see `test-work` print on your page response

Comment: na nothing on the screen i think phtml file is not getting called inside controller

Comment: Added `$this->getResponse()->setBody($blockHtml);
            return;` on first of execute() function

Comment: yeah i have tried that

Comment: amit i fixed it and am updating my ans so that somebody may find it thanks for your effort

Comment: You donot need to load  layout againa

Comment: I have test with `public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $blockHtml = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
            ->setBlockId('contact-us-shortcuts')
            ->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($blockHtml);
        return;}`

Comment: it working fine

Comment: am laoding layout just for my comfort will remove once am done and the i dont know why that code didnt your code worked for me

Answer (score 0):

this is how i fixed this

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;
    
        protected $requestforquoteFactory;
    
        protected $requestforquote;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Vendor\Module\Model\RequestForQuoteFactory $requestforquoteFactory,
            \Vendor\Module\Model\RequestForQuote $requestforquote
        )
        {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->requestforquoteFactory = $requestforquoteFactory;
            $this->requestforquote = $requestforquote;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
       
        public function execute()
        {
    
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
                $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Rfq')
                    ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::rfq_form.phtml')
                    ->toHtml();
                $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
                $this->_view->renderLayout();
                $this->_view->loadLayout();
    
                try{
    
                $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                $name = $request['name'];
                $company = $request['company'];
                $phonenumber = $request['phonenumber'];
                $email = $request['email'];
                // $email = $request['email'];
                $gstnumber = $request['gstnumber'];
        
                $requestforquote = $this->requestforquoteFactory->create();
    
                 $requestforquote->setName($name);
                 $requestforquote->setCompany($company);
                 $requestforquote->setPhoneNumber($phonenumber);
                 $requestforquote->setGSTNumber($gstnumber);
                 $requestforquote->setEmail($email);
                 $requestforquote->save();
                
                $message = __('Thank you! Your Quote Has Been Submitted');
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
    
                $this->resultPageFactory->create();
                //return $resultRedirect->setPath('requestforquote/index/index');
                $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
                $this->_view->renderLayout();
                $this->_view->loadLayout();
    
            }catch (\Exception $e){
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t submit your request, Please try again.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                //return $resultRedirect->setPath('requestforquote/index/index');
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```